# JQuery mobile run time change html (jQuery('#xx').html(html);)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I took the code in: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/about/getting-started.html
it works fine,

then I try to build the same dynamically , but this not works at all!
Empty page!!!!!!!
here, not works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     var html = '';

     html += '<div data-role="page">';

     html += '<div data-role="header">';
     html += '<h1>My Title</h1>';
     html += '</div>';

     html += '<div data-role="content">';
     html += '<p>Hello world</p>    ';
     html += '</div>';

     html += '</div>';
     jQuery('#divData').html(html);
     return false;
 });
```

And this HTML:

```
<div id="divData"> 
</div>
```

WHY?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function init () {
        var html = '';

        html += '<div data-role="page">';

        html += '<div data-role="header">';
        html += '<h1>My Title</h1>';
        html += '</div>';

        html += '<div data-role="content">';
        html += '<p>Hello world</p>    ';
        html += '</div>';

        html += '</div>';
        $('#divData').html(html);
    }

    init();
 });

<div id="divData"> 
</div>
```

Cleaned up your code. And I think the problem was what you used jQuery and not $ to do the innerhtml.

Comment: the problem was: conflict on one of the JS.